# Laravel 5 and Neo4j remote connection with NeoEloquent

Tags: laravel, neo4j, laravel-5, neoeloquent

Im with Laravel 5 and NeoEloquent (Neo4j). I have a no-ip domain to my computer and Neo4j local and the web on a hosting. I setup web to connecto to my computer no-ip but still not work. Port 7474 is open trought my router.

Also uncomment on neo4j-server.conf:

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I get it that you're running Neo4j on localhost:7474, all you have to do is add the configuration in your `database.php` as mentioned in the docs here: https://github.com/vinelab/neoeloquent#configuration